# Relacionar un campo de tabla con muchos registros en mysql

Tags: mysql, diagrama-er

quisiera relacionar una tabla llamada 'proveedores' con una tabla llamada 'zona_cobertura', en donde un proveedor (ej: DHL) puede cubrir varias zonas (países y regiones). Sin embargo no se me ocurre en qué forma estructurar la tabla para poder lograr que un proveedor tenga varias zonas de cobertura y no solo una con el id_zona_cobertura.
Agradezco sus comentarios.

La tabla de proveedores esta creada:

```
CREATE TABLE proveedores (
                id_proveedor CHAR(10),
                nombre VARCHAR(50),
                calle VARCHAR(50),
                numero VARCHAR(6),
                telefono CHAR(12),
                email VARCHAR(50),
                ciudad VARCHAR(50),
                poblacion INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_proveedor)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE zona_cobertura (
                id_zona_cobertura,
                pais_cobertura VARCHAR(50),
                region_cobertura VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (id_zona_cobertura)
);
```

```
ALTER TABLE PROVEEDORES
ADD id_zona_cobertura;
```

```
ALTER TABLE PROVEEDORES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (region_cobertura) REFERENCES zona_cobertura(region_cobertura),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (pais_cobertura) REFERENCES zona_cobertura(pais_cobertura);
```

Comment: Pues es lo mismo que tu dices tienes que hacer una relación 1:N de 1 proveedor puede tener N zonas de cobertura

Comment: Pues te falta una tabla intermedia, que una las dos. Lee por favor sobre normalizacion y tercera forma normal.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te va a servir:

```
CREATE TABLE proveedores (
                id_proveedor CHAR(10),
                nombre VARCHAR(50),
                calle VARCHAR(50),
                numero VARCHAR(6),
                telefono CHAR(12),
                email VARCHAR(50),
                ciudad VARCHAR(50),
                poblacion INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_proveedor)
);

CREATE TABLE zona_cobertura (
                id_zona_cobertura int not null auto_increment,
                pais_cobertura VARCHAR(50),
                region_cobertura VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (id_zona_cobertura)
);

CREATE TABLE proveedores_zonas (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    id_proveedor char(10) null,
    id_zona int not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint ui_prov_zona unique (id_proveedor, id_zona)
);
alter table proveedores_zonas add constraint fk_prov_zona_prov foreign key (id_proveedor) references proveedores(id_proveedor);
alter table proveedores_zonas add constraint fk_prov_zona_zona foreign key (id_zona) references zona_cobertura(id_zona_cobertura);
```

La tabla `proveedores_zonas` te relaciona las tablas de proveedores y zonas de forma tal que un proveedor pueda tener varias zonas y a la vez que no se puedan duplicar las zonas por proveedor (`unique index`).

¿Por qué el código de proveedor es un `char(10)`?
He añadido `int not null auto_increment` a la definición del id de la zona.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas